# $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{x^2+y^2} dxdy$

Tags: definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, iterated-integrals

I would like to solve the given integral:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{x^2+y^2} dxdy$$

The integral is doable just using the regular iterated integral with $x$ and $y$. We integrate with respect to $x$ first with the substitution $x=y\tan{\theta}$, and we end up with:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\arctan{(\frac{1}{y})}}y^2\sec^3{\theta}d\theta dy$$

This... ends up to be really ugly. We turn it into the form:

$$\frac{1}{2}\int \left[\sqrt{1+y^2}+y^2\ln{(1+\sqrt{1+y^2}})-y^2\ln{y}\right]dy$$

Again, really ugly, but I've managed to wring out an answer of $\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{3}\ln{(1+\sqrt{2}}).$

My question: Is there another way to do this? My instict is to turn the bounds into polar, so the integrand becomes just $r$. But.... a square is the *last* thing to turn into polar. How would we do the integral to turn it into polar?

And my second question, is there a more elegant way to do the integral better than both of these?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using polar coordinates instead?

Comment: Polar coordinates aren't that bad here.

Comment: How would I put a square into polar?

Comment: You need to find the length of the piece of circle of radius $r> 1$ contained in the square, it will involve some $arcos(1/r)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \sqrt{x^2+y^2 } \, dy \, dx &= 2  \int_0^{\frac{\pi}4} \int_0^{\sec \theta} r^2 \, dr d \theta \\
&= \frac23 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}4} \sec^3 \theta \,d\theta \\
 &= \frac23 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}4} \sec\theta (\sec^2 )\theta \,d\theta
\end{align}

Try to complete the task.

Comment: Is there some kind of nice formula for $\int_{[0,1]^n} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i ^2}dV$?

Comment: @Luna145 the argument in this answer lets you derive it :)

Comment: Aren’t you missing a factor of $1/3$ starting in the second line from the $r^2$ integral?

Comment: oops, you are right, thanks.